# Query regarding RF

Tags: rf, radio

I have few questions about RF.

1. In the RF they will mention the term "transmitting power." What does it exactly mean, if the transmitting power is more then what will happen?
2. If they mention a frequency 865 to 867 MHz, does it mean it works in only that frequency? Can it be tuned to other frequencies?
3. Please share me a reference doc were I can go through the basics of RF.

Comment: Go read the datasheets. Eg https://www.rfidinc.com/uhf-oem-level-rfid-microreaders

Comment: What do you mean by "RF" ("1. In the _RF_...")? Who are "they"? What is "it" ("_it_ works...", "Can _it_ be tuned ...")? Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

In the absense of information in the question, [this](https://www.ofcom.org.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0025/38095/final_report.pdf) document suggests that the 865 to 867MHz band is used in the UK for RFID purposes, and it's likely many other territories around the world use the same frequency range for the same thing.

1) Transmitting power means the power the transmitter is rated or measured to produce. It will often be the power measured on a power meter that's connected instead of the antenna on a test board, during a type test. Transmitter power is limited to limit the range of the device, and interference to other RF users. Licensing regulations only permit devices to be sold that produce less than the maximum for that particular license. It's not permitted under the terms of the license to try to increase the radiated power by using a directional antenna, and it would probably be difficult to increase the power by tweaking the circuit.

2) It's only intended to work in the 865 to 867 band. Some components may be dedicated to that frequency, some components may be broader band. Any firmware in the device will certainly be fixed to that band. It may be possible to find hacks to both hardware and firmware by searching for the specific part number online.

3) Start off with my link in the opening paragraph. Then hit wikipedia.